# Why is the `+=` operator seemingly ignored in my PHP script?

Tags: php

Sorry for asking in the wrong category. Would post directly in SO if I actually were able: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346772/i-dont-seem-to-be-able-to-register-a-stack-exchange-account Feel free to move this.

***Working code***

```
$rows =
[
    [ 'a', '1' ],
    [ 'b', '2' ],
    [ 'c', '3' ]
];
var_dump($rows);
```

***Good output***

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

***Non-working code***

```
$rows = [];
$rows += [ 'a', '1' ];
$rows += [ 'b', '2' ];
$rows += [ 'c', '3' ];
var_dump($rows);
```

***Bad output***

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

I also tried `$rows .= ...`, but it also doesn't work.

I cannot "just use the first version" because in the actual script, it's not all defined in the same place; it's generated in various loops and stuff in a large script. That's why I need to "add to the rows array" in the manner above, which I actually thought I had done in the past without problems. Apparently not?

Answer (score 1):

The "+=" operator gives the union of both arrays, and with a union, with indexes existing in both, those of the left array take precedence.  See [PHP manual: array operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).   I'll explain:

```
$rows = [];  
$rows += [ 'a', '1' ];
```

as $rows was empty, it now contains [ 0 => 'a', 1 => '1' ]

$rows += [ 'b', '2' ];

as the union of [ 0 => 'a', 1 => '1' ] and [ 0 => 'b', 1 => '2' ] is [ 0 => 'a', 1 => '1' ], $rows remains unchanged.

```
$rows += [ 'c', '3' ];
```

idem dito.

I can show you how to obtain the desired result:

```
$rows = [];
$rows[] = [ 'a', '1' ];
$rows[] = [ 'b', '2' ];
$rows[] = [ 'c', '3' ];
var_dump($rows);
```

which gives

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```